# finding partial derivatives in nested function

Tags: derivatives

[image]

I am just trying to understand if I understand partial derivatives. Is this ok?

Comment: If I well understand it is $c=x*y*p*m$. Right?  If so, and $y,p,m$ do not depend on $x$ what is the derivative with respect to $x$?

Comment: Hm, so let's assume b = square(a). In this case, partial derivative would make sense right?